# Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH and 3TB WD My Book Essential

Tags: router, usb-storage, buffalo-router

I have a Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH and a 3TB Western Digital MyBook Essential that I wish to use as a NAS, I have formatted the drive with a single XFS partition, but when I plug it into the router the Disk Management page says "No identifiable partitions."

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just to check: you're using the stock firmware (which is claimed to support XFS) and your drive has a GPT partition table and the partition works fine under *nix?

Comment: Hello, yes, I have used Ubuntu to format it, and it works fine in that using GPT/XFS

Comment: I am also using FW 1.77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffalo have since confirmed that this router only supports external drives up to 2TB.